# iOS invert left and right on screen

Tags: ios

Is there anyway to invert left and right in iOS, such that the phone looks as it would in a mirror?  (Yes all text would be backward, this is a desired effect.)  Not just a specific app that displays itself in reverse, but a system-wide effect like inverting colours.  It would probably not be a generally sought feature, one that apple would likely implement itself, but perhaps a third-party app exists?

Comment: This is hilarious! Might one ask why?

Comment: I often take notes or otherwise write in public (and in private) using mirror writing to prevent others from copying/reading what I write, but my own reading speed of mirror writing is much reduced because I only have my own writings to practice on, unlike websites/ebooks/text messages/etc. Looking for additional practice, and my iphone is what I do most casual reading on.  Also, it seems like a good prank to play on someone.

Comment: What are you some kind of a spy? Seems kind of extreme. Doubt this would be possible without a jailbreak and even then I doubt someone made this. However, why not use a Bluetooth keyboard to type and just turn the phone face down so people can't read the screen.

Comment: You misunderstand.  My mirror note-taking is long-hand, pad to paper, and unrelated to my request.  This switch for my iphone would just be for practice reading mirrored text, not for any desire of privacy.

Comment: Would be very very handy if you want to turn your I phone into a HUD display using only your windscreen or a simple half mirror...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar app for video (projector issues), I came across a lot of mirror apps that were mainly for photo's and other images but some for text, others for both, as we as for inverting colours. Just search "mirror" in the app store.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please notice to `system-wide` constraint. It is better to find that app in Appstore and provide a link to it to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might find yourself with some video which has been reversed in this way, and you need to correct it.

One way to do it is to copy the video to photos. Then you select it, press edit, press crop, and up in the top let of the screen you've got an icon that lets you o it. You need to wait till it’s done the job - there’re a little round indicator showing how far it’s done that. Then you can shift the unreversed video to some more convenient app if you want.

There may be an app that does this, but I haven't found one. One problem is that "reverse" or "flip" is normally taken to mean reverse the direction of video time, or portrait to landscape image.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried any of these, but this question sounds similar enough to potentially be of some use:

[horizonally flip OSX's monitor output?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91174/horizonally-flip-osxs-monitor-output)  Asked by **Joe** May 12th of 2013.

Two answers listed there; one with a positive vote count.

Comment: Good for OS X.  But not for iOS, which is what this question mentions.

Comment: @ GEdgar Ah... you're right.  I read the "app" in the first answer, leapt to a conclusion, and... well... shucks.  Maybe someone can use it as a jumping off point to get a real answer?