# Is it possible to flip the internal display's y-coordinate?

Tags: display

I've had too bad neck posture while I've been using my laptop. Looking down too much have led to chronic pain in my neck.

Experimenting around with possible solutions to this, I found that placing a mirror in front of my eyes is very effective for correcting my posture, while still using the internal display. However, this mirrors the y-coordinate of the display so I wonder if it's possible to mirror it back?

I'm running macOS Catalina on an ancient MBP 13 Retina.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what is meant by Y coordinate. What is your destination?

Comment: Related question about flipping horizontally, do any of these work for you vertically? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/91174/37797

Comment: @Darwin y coordinates are vertical, so the question is asking about inverting the y axis.

Comment: It doesn't flip the y-coordinate, but I have found a music stand helps my posture (and neck) when sitting in a comfy chair.